# Customer Bookings Graph API getStaffAvailability endpoint returning wrong data

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-booking

Using the [getStaffAvailability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingbusiness-getstaffavailability?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint from Graph API to determine the availability of the staff, status of staff is returned as 'busy' despite the cancellation of appointment from the calendar and the appointment not existing on the calendar for any staff for that date and time slot. Similarly, staff time off slots on the calendar are not returned as 'busy'.

Could I be misinterpreting the concept of staff availability with regards to this endpoint?

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with Graph bookings and availabilities.
I've expirienced a very similar problem: Timeslots returning as available while they should be marked as busy.

Posted to [Microsoft Answers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/976005/bookingsbusiness-getstaffavailability-does-not-alw.html) and the [Graph Github](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1455).
Hoping to get a reply there soon.